# laravel check if user is active?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

using laravel 4 I am trying to add 'active' column to my database to check if the user is active and is not suspended , here is my migration users table.

```
public function up()
{
    //
     Schema::create(
        'users',
        function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email', 300);
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->boolean('active'); // check this one
            $table->string('first_name', 100);
            $table->string('last_name', 100);
            $table->string('address', 250)->nullable();
            $table->string('city', 100)->nullable();
            $table->string('state', 2)->nullable();
            $table->string('zip', 5)->nullable();
            $table->string('phone', 10)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        }
    );
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

could you help me if I use $table->boolean('active'); // check this one

****is this the right way to do it? so I can use the Auth class like this to check if the user is active or not? ****

```
$is_active = Auth::user()->active;

if (!$is_active == 1)
   {
echo "Account not activated";
   }
```

Comment: Apart from naming it 'active' instead of 'activated' it's ok. If you ever want to add a field telling you a user is not active (disabled or whatever) it will be easier to read.

Comment: but how laravel reads it 'active' or 'activated' or it doesn't really matter laravel will know?

Comment: or you mean if I made it 'activated' then to check : Auth::user()->activated;  ?

Comment: I meant only that it will be more readable for you should you ever want to have fields activated (like clicked email link) and active (ie. not disabled/suspended), no difference for laravel. Of cource you call it on the user() like you named it in the table :)

Comment: That looks correct to me. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: thanks for all your help :) I just wanted to double check its correct

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the way you have mentioned but the Laravel way to do this exists

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1)))
{
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

Read : [Laravel\Docs\Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users)

Just my 2 bit : The way are building you database is not advised. You should keep your user login information (`email`, `password` & `active`) in `users` table and others in a separate `user_profile` table. Later you can use [eloquent to map relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).

Comment: If I may ask, what are the advantages of separating the login and profile information into different tables?

Comment: You get a lean authentication table, making queries faster. You can then bloat your user_profile table with as required columns as you want.